# How to solve LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'vtkCommonCore-9.0.lib'

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk, opencascade

I use the library **OpenCasCade** for a C++ project on ***windows***. I have updated it to *7.4.0* with **conda**. A new version of **vtk** (*vtk-9.0.1*) came with it

I build the project with **CMake**. There was no problem before the update and since, when I compile I have the message `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'vtkCommonCore-9.0.lib`.

I tried to link directly **vtk** with `find_package` without success...

It would be nice if someone has a clue ?

Comment: Can not open a library is one or more of 3 things. 1. The path and / or file name you specified is wrong, 2. You are mixing 32 and 64 bit, 3. The file is corrupt

Comment: ***I tried to link directly vtk with find_package without success.*** Maybe you should ask a different question about that showing a minimal CMakeLists.txt and the output that you saw. Without more information no one can help fix this.

Comment: Are you trying to build *Open CASCADE Technology* with VTK 9.0 dependency (e.g. for *TKIVtk* toolkit), or you are building an application? In the first case - have you tried OCCT 7.5.0 beta which is expected to build fine with VTK 9.0?

Comment: @gkv311 I' m trying to build an application but unfortunately I don't have access to OCCT 7.5.0.

Comment: @albator, OK, it is just unclear from question how it is related to OCCT.
OCCT 7.5.0 beta is available publicly (but I suppose not yet in conda)
https://dev.opencascade.org/index.php?q=node/1305

Comment: But as you don't use TKIVtk in your application, then OCCT version is not important here (as VTK is an optional dependency and the most simplest way is just building OCCT without VTK; although I don't get why CMake tries to link to VTK in this case...).

Comment: @gkv311, Perhaps I was unclear.  Before having updated OCCT, I didn't include any VTK package in my CMakeLists.txt. But after OCCT update, I got the compile error. So I added VTK package in my CMakeLists.txt. But nothing changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested on this link
[vtk_link](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/md__home_kitware_dashboards_buildbot_vtk_nightly-master-ike-linux-shared-release_doc_nightly_osm5be4e3c8a508a13e731d7b85aeec815a.html)

I added the command in my CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(VTK  REQUIRED  COMPONENTS CommonCore RenderingOpenGL2)
```

But nothing changed.

Finally,
I have solved the problem. From conda the package *OCCT* came with a *vtk* dependency. I have chosen the same *OCCT* version (7.4.0) but with a former build number. It solves the problem.

Comment: This does not look like a good solution to the problem. Remember the Answer section is for solutions not additional information or questions.

Comment: Sorry I 'm new on _Stackoverflow_. The problem I think comes from **opencascade**  wich I include with `find_package(OpenCASCADE REQUIRED)` because I don't need **vtk** for the moment in my project. When I got the error message I thought I had to link **vtk** but it doesn't help.